# How to "go to definition" to a method of super class in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, wsl-2

I am familiar with Pycharm and new to VSCode. I would like to "go to definition" like I did in Pycharm but I can't figure out how to. Btw I set up the environment in WSL2 Ubuntu and code from local with WSL VSCode extension.

```
Directory tree view is like :
src
 |-calculation
    |-base_class.py
    |-particular_class.py
 |-db_related_module
    |-db_class.py
```

and each module has:

base_class.py

```
class BaseClass():

    def __init__(self, DbClass):
        self.db_cls = DbClass
```

particular_class.py

```
from base_class import BaseClass
from db_related_module.db_class import DbClass


class ParticularCalClass(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            DbClass
        )

    def some_calculation(self):
        do_db_stuff = self.db_cls
        ret = do_db_stuff.execute_sql()
        return ret


def main():
    calc_cls = ParticularCalClass()
    print(calc_cls.some_calculation())

main()
```

db_class.py

```
class DbClass():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def execute_sql():
        return "execute some sql"
```

Here I would like to jump from particular_class.py

```
ret = do_db_stuff.execute_sql()
```

to db_class.py

```
def execute_sql():
```

as it is the definition.

Comment: ctrl + click on `execute_sql`

Comment: I did that. It won't work.

Comment: does it work with other functions?

Comment: Yes unless it refers to inherited method like the case above.

Answer (score 1):

After testing this is the same problem on my machine. So I filed a report on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20474) and here is their response:

> The import in line `from base_class import BaseClass` is incorrect in this scenario. It should be `from calculation.base_class import BaseClass`. And you will need to have `PYTHONPATH=./src`. If you have `from base_class import BaseClass` python won't know where the `base_class` module is, so you won't see go to definition working. you will wither have to add `calculation`  directory to `sys.path` or change the import as I recommended above.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. 
Hmm I doubt this because, 
1. without any change, Python knows where to resolve the reference in fact Python can execute the main function with no problem.
2. Pycharm manages to resolve the reference without any changes (so I assume this scenario is not wrong).
3. Even after I change to "from calculation.base_class import BaseClass", VScode still cannot resolve the reference with "src/" set to PYTHONPATH of cource.

Comment: If you get an answer on GitHub, you can write it here and accept it to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Normally that would be using `F12`, or right click and go to definition.

Comment: Somehow it won't work in this case